# Jquery respond to find() fail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

I found this code that let´s me traverse through some xml elements:

```
$(somexml).find('company[id="'+id+'"] customers customer').each(function()
{
     var $tmp = $(this);
     alert($tmp.attr('customerid'));
});
```

seems to work pretty good. But since i´m novice at Javascript/Jquery i have some questions:

1. How can i respond to when the find() failed...no matches?
2. Why the '$' before tmp? Why not just **var tmp = $(this);**

Comment: The '$' before tmp is just a convention followed to indicate that `tmp` is a jQuery object and not plain js.

Comment: Thx Clyde for your answer. So i can just use it as tmp instead of $tmp? Tried it, it seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: `each` returns the object it's been called on, that is `$(x).each` returns `$(x)`. So, assign the result of each to a variable and check its length:

```
var obj = $(somexml).find(whatever).each(function() {
    ...
});
if(!obj.length)
     nothing has been found...
```

2: `$tmp` instead of just `tmp` is a ["hungarian"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) convention to denote jQuery objects. You are not required to use it.

Comment: @thg435 - Thx a bunch! Nicely explained. Really helpful!
atif089 - I +1 it. Haven´t seen it until now.

Answer (score 1):

How can i respond to when the find() failed...no matches?

> Assign the result to some variable

```
result = $(somexml).find('company[id="'+id+'"] customers customer');

if(result.length > 0)
{
   result.each(function()
   {
       var $tmp = $(this);
       alert($tmp.attr('customerid'));
   });    
}    
else
{
   alert("No results");
}
```

> Why the '$' before tmp? Why not just var tmp = $(this);

```
You do not need to use $ before tmp. using $ 

var tmp = $(this);
```